# What if there's a Minyan of Aveilim?

Tags: tefilla, mourning-aveilus, chazzan-prayer-leader, minyan

It is my understanding that when one is in the year of mourning following the death of certain relatives, he is not allowed to lead ["daven from the amud"] certain prayers (such as those on Shabbos, Yom Tov, Rosh Chodesh and Chol Hamoed).

If so, what would happen if all 10 people gathered to daven are in fact mourners? Would any of them be able to lead the prayers? What would they do?

(of course, correct me if my initial assumption is incorrect)

Comment: Can't a similar question be asked about a minyan of Kohanim on Sabbat? Who gets aliyah number 3?

Comment: @soandos, there's a _s'if_ in _SA_ about just that case, and my father tells me there used to be a community in upstate New York that was in fact all _kohanim_.

Comment: also, who says "amen" to their kaddish?

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman Sounds like a nice question. Care to ask it?

Comment: @yydl Actually I try to avoid halacha l'maisa questions here. You're free to ask if you're interested.

Comment: @msh210 - I once heard that there was a Sephardic country or island somewhere in which only Kohanim lived, without other levites or israelites.

Comment: @AdamMosheh Djerba.

Answer (score 5):

Clearly, one of them would have to lead. The choice minhag not to have a mourner lead the tefillah on Shabbat or Yom tov is a matter of who is **preferred** to take the post ([because of the honor of the tzibbur](http://ohr.edu/2258)), not an absolute disqualification.

Comment: Sounds okay. Do you have a source for that?

Comment: No, but it seems like an obvious inference.

Comment: Do you at least have a source for your claim it's "becuase of the honor of the tzibbur"?

Comment: Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 26:14 says that it's a custom. It also says that if a person (regularly?) led services on Shabbat before becomign a mourner, he can continue to do so even while he's a mourner.

Comment: http://ohr.edu/2258

Answer (score 5):

The [Shach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shach#The_.22Shakh.22) ([YD 376 sk 14](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9147&st=&pgnum=380)) rules that if there is no one who is as qualified to lead, the mourner may lead even on Shabbat. If no one else is even there, I presume the mourner is the most qualified.