# Aveilus and Davening from the Omud on Rosh Hashana / Yom Kippur?

Tags: halacha, yom-kippur, chazzan-prayer-leader, mourning-aveilus, rosh-hashanah-new-year

Can a Ba'al tefillah in his year of aveilus daven from the Omud on Rosh Hashana / Yom Kippur?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Mr. 5337, and thank you for bringing your question!  Off the top of my head, it depends if the Ba'al Tefillah in question is qualitatively replaceable or not.  When I was in Yeshiva, there were two aveilim who were brothers and chazzanim for different tefillos - one davened from the amud and the other did not. (I am going to fix your grammar for you, but you could also [edit](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/37626/edit) it yourself)

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16806/759

Comment: See the Mahaber in the Shulchun Aruch,  "lo nahogu..." (it is not our custom), on which the Mogen Avraham writes using the language issur and hetur (forbidden and permitted). And I recall that the Mishne Brurah goes into the subject of one who holds the offical post of shliach tzibur, or makes his living from this in yom tov.  But in any case none of us are the one to decide a question like this unless we happen to be the Rabbi for that particular shul.

Comment: *"Well you knew my dad was deaf", he said // "Last night he pasted away. // It's the first time that my father's // Heard me pray".* -- Deaf Man in the Shteibel, Country Yossi
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qKC9KNQUZbs

Answer (score 4):

From [Penei Baruch Siman 29](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47632&st=&pgnum=339):

> אבל תוך י״ב חודש על אביו ואמו ובתוך שלשים על שאר  קרובים אסור לעבור
>   לפני התיבה בראש השנה ויום הכיפורים.  וכשאין אחר כמותו מותר

My loose translation: A mourner within 30 days of the passing of all relatives and within 12 months of his father or mother is forbidden to be a chazzan on Rosh Hashana and Yom Kippur. However if there is none other like him it is permitted.

Comment: I believe that the "there is none other like him applies to a regularly appointed (paid) Chazzan who has this as his annual job, or a shul's full-time chazzan. And, it would apply even if they could find someone else. The regular chazzan has "priority".