# Is there a preference for a grandson or for another person to say kaddish if the son is indisposed

Tags: halacha, tefilla, kaddish

Is there a preference for a grandson or for another person to say kaddish if the son is indisposed?

---

I am asking this generally, although I was motivated by the following scenario:

I have yahrzeit for my mother in a week's time. I am suffering from a severe disc problem and may not be able to get to shul. Is it better to ask my son to say kaddish for my mother (his grandmother) or should I ask someone else? My son has never been an aval and his natural feeling is that he shouldn't say kaddish while his parents are alive.

Comment: Get well soon!!

Comment: You should consider just studying extra Torah that day or giving extra charity.

Comment: *Refuah shelemah* and may this Torah learning be in the merit of your mother `A"H.

Comment: I did say kaddish for an aunt who had no children at the request of my mother (while both parents were alive). He can say it for your mother at your request, but it may be better to have someone who has already said kaddish for a parent do so. That way he does not have the feeling that he is putting you in a bad position.

Comment: Mi Yodeya! Can you [edit] your question to make it less personal? We [try to avoid practical halachic questions](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1734). You might also want to see "[Why is it necessary to ask a rabbi?](//judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146)" for more info. We hope to see you around!

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/77570/759

Comment: Whoever takes precedence in inheritance, takes precedence in saying Kaddishim.

Comment: @Alberko sounds like an answer if you can source it!

Comment: I am sorry for your loss.  I hope you will also be able to get community members to come to you at some point so you can also say kaddish even if you can not travel.

Answer (score 1):

The father of a guy in our *minyan* is not *Shomer Mizwot* and his father (i.e. the original guy's paternal grandfather) passed away. I asked my Rav if the guy in our minyan can recite *Qaddish* in memory of his paternal grandfather in place of his father - may he live and be well.

My Rav replied:

1. He must request permission from his father (whose father passed away)
2. He should recite *Qaddish `Al Yisra'el* year-round
3. He should recite *Qaddish Yehe Shelama* during the week in which his paternal grandfather passed away
4. He should hold a *Se`udat Azkarah* (memorial meal) in honor of his paternal grandfather on the day he passed away

Based on my Rav's ruling, I would suggest:

1. Explicitly granting your son permission to recite *Qaddish* in honor of your mother
2. Having your son recite all of the *Qaddishim* which you would have recited yourself

In other words, all other things equal (including the assumption that your son will be able to properly recite *Qaddish*), there is no need to delegate the *Qaddish* to anyone other than your son - may you all live and be well.

As always, CYLOR.

Comment: My father has specifically asked me to say kaddish when there is no avel in schul. Unfortunately, that is rarely the case.

Comment: While this only discusses males, you may need the Kaddish-sayer to get permission from both of his parents.

Comment: The OP did not specify whether he is Ashkenazi or Sephardi. The Rav cited above appears to be giving instructions according to the Edot Hamizrach. The OP should follow his own customs and CYLOR.

Comment: @Epicentre I don't see how you inferred that from my answer or what your comment added. I too ended by stating clearly to CYLOR.