# Does a kohen get preference when making a siyum?

Tags: halacha, kohen-priest, siyum

If a few people finished a massechet of gemara together, one of whom is a kohen, should the kohen be given the kavod of reciting the kaddish just as we give mezumin to a kohen or does it not matter?

Comment: Why is this different than any other kaddish with multiple people to say it such as mourners? eg http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/77570/759

Comment: @DoubleAA Because here there is only opportunity for kaddish and the kaddish is not a mourner's kaddish, it is the special kaddish upon making a siyyum

Answer (score 1):

[Rabbi Kaganoff](http://rabbikaganoff.com/the-mitzvah-of-vikidashto-to-treat-a-kohen-with-respect-2/) notes the following examples where the Kohen recieves preference before others:

- “The kohen should open first (liftoach rishon), he should bless first, and he should take a nice portion first” (Gittin 59b, Moed Katan 28b).
- "The kohen should make the brocha on the meal first (Rashi, Gittin 59b), make kiddush for everyone (Mishnah Berurah 201:12) and lead the benching (Rashi, Moed Katan 28b; Ran and other Rishonim, Nedarim 62b)."
- "Poskim rule that a kohen should be chosen ahead of a levi or a yisroel to be chazan (Pri Megadim, Eishel Avraham 53:14). Presumably, he should also be given preference for a position to be a Rav, Rosh Yeshiva, or Magid Shiur in a yeshiva, if he is qualified for the position."

It would seem the Kohen would be given preference over others at the siyum.

Comment: I don't see the correlation. It seems that the above is a specific list of situations.