Removing someone as chazzan
If someone started davening as chazzan are you allowed to remove him and have someone else continue against his will? Is there a difference if he only started a minor part (i.e. said ve'hu rachum by maariv, or ashrei by mincha and didn't say kadish or barechu yet) but didn't say a part that halachically needs a minyan yet?

If he omits Birkat haMinim, or says "modim modim," we remove him from the 'amud

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/77570/759 OC 53:20 אם אחד רוצה לומר תפלה בשביל אביו ואחד רוצה לומר בשביל אחר מי שירצה הקהל שיאמר התפלה הוא יאמר Whoever the community wants should do it. Don't see why it matters if he started already
